# not able to remove the white border from the infowindow

Tags: html, css, infowindow

Hi I am using the following CSS to remove the extra white borderfrom the info window it works fine with the provided Height & width in the CSS
But I am using 2 Infowindows & both the Infowidows' s have different Height & Width so when I adjust the Height & width as per 1 Info Window an Extra White Border appears for the another Info Window

Is there any way I can remove the White border from both the Infowindows. I have tried for setting the Height & Width to Auto but didnt succeed

```
// --------------java script-----------------

                 var iwOuter1 = $('.gm-style-iw');

                /*
                 * Since this div is in a position prior to .gm-div
                 * style-iw. We use jQuery and create a iwBackground
                 * variable, and took advantage of the existing reference
                 * .gm-style-iw for the previous div with .prev().
                 */
                var iwBackground1 = iwOuter1.prev();

                // Removes background shadow DIV
                iwBackground1.children(':nth-child(2)').css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });

                // Removes white background DIV
                iwBackground1.children(':nth-child(4)').css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });

                // Changes the desired tail shadow color.
                iwBackground1.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({
                    'box-shadow': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0px 1px 6px',
                    'z-index': '1'
                });

                // Reference to the div that groups the close button
                // elements.
                var iwCloseBtn1 = iwOuter1.next();

                // Apply the desired effect to the close button
                iwCloseBtn1.css({
                    opacity: '1',
                    right: '74px',
                    top: '25px'
                });

                // If the content of infowindow not exceed the set maximum
                // height, then the gradient is removed.
                if ($('.iw-content').height() < 140) {
                    $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({
                        display: 'none'
                    });
                }

                // The API automatically applies 0.7 opacity to the button
                // after the mouseout event. This function reverses this
                // event to the desired value.
                iwCloseBtn1.mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        opacity: '1'
                    });
                });
            });

        }

     -------------------css-----------------
 .gm-style-iw {
max-width:480px; 
min-width:200px;
top: 15px !important;
left: 0px !important;
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
}

#iw-container {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#iw-container .iw-title {
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 10px;
color: #3399ff;
text-align: left;
margin: 0;
background-color:#f6d9bb;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
border-bottom: 3px solid black;
height: 100%; 

}
#iw-container .iw-title1 {
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
 #iw-container .iw-content {
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
margin-right: 1px;
padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
max-height: 140px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.iw-content img {
float: right;
margin: 0 5px 5px 10px; 
}
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or html part ? it's a bit hard to understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u use a `border-width: 0px !important;`?

Its hard to understand what you're trying to do without a visual example.